# Keep the check mark after form is submitted

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, forms

I have 2 forms that they need to be used to make a report. The first form gets data from the database (MariaDB) onchange of one of the cells (the on change events happens when the user checks the cell with the report) once that the cell is selected with the details of the report, those details are used on submit by the second form. Until that point everything is perfect. The problem is that I can't keep the check mark on the cell of the first form once that it is selected because the page is reloaded onchange. That makes the user believe that they didn't select any report.

So, what I want to do is to keep checked the cell of the first form after it gets the data from the database. Then, the user will click on "Submit" to submit the second form.

Kind regards and thanks in advance for your help!

```
<form name="f1" id="form1" action="" method="post"> 
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>Assets </th>
            <th>Description </th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <?php
                while($agency_row = $agency_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $value1 = str_replace(' ','&nbsp;',str_pad($agency_row["agency"], -10));
                $value2 = str_replace(' ','&nbsp;',str_pad($agency_row["report_name"], 70));
                $formatedDate = date("D M d H:i:s Y", $agency_row["scan_end"]);
                $value3 = str_replace(' ','&nbsp;',str_pad($formatedDate, 20));
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><input onchange='f1.submit()'; type='checkbox' class='i-checks' name='agency' value='" . $value1 . ":" . $agency_row["report_name"] . ":" . $agency_row["scan_start"] . ":" . $agency_row["scan_end"] . "'></td>";
                echo "<td>$value1</td>";
                echo "<td>$value2</td>";
                echo "<td>$formatedDate</td>";
                echo "<td>$value3</td>";
                echo "</tr>";    
                }?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>

<form name="f2" id="form2" action="report.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="agency" value="<?php echo "$agency";?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="report_name" value="<?php echo "$report_name";?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="scan_start" value="<?php echo "$scan_start";?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="scan_end" value="<?php echo "$scan_end";?>">
  <input type="hidden" value="yes" name="isPlugName">
  <input type="hidden" value="yes" name="isPlugFam">
  <input type="hidden" value="yes" name="isPlugInfo">
  <input type="hidden" value="yes" name="isSynopsis">
  <input type="hidden" value="yes" name="isDescription">
  <input type="hidden" value="yes" name="isSolution">
  <input type="hidden" value="yes" name="isSeeAlso">
  <input type="hidden" value="yes" name="isPlugOut">
  <input type="hidden" value="plugin" name="byVuln">
  <input type="hidden" value="yes" name="isCvss">
  <input type="hidden" value="yes" name="isVulnPub">
  <input type="hidden" value="yes" name="isExploit">
  <input type="hidden" value="yes" name="isCve">
  <input type="hidden" value="yes" name="isBid">
  <input type="hidden" value="yes" name="isOsvdb">
  <input type="hidden" value="yes" name="isCert">
  <input type="hidden" value="yes" name="isIava">
  <input type="hidden" value="yes" name="isCWE">
  <input type="hidden" value="yes" name="isMS">
  <input type="hidden" value="yes" name="isSec">
  <input type="hidden" value="yes" name="isEdb">
  <input type="hidden" value="yes" name="isAffected">
  <input type="hidden" value="yes" name="isService">
  <input type="hidden" value="4" name="critical">
  <input type="hidden" value="3" name="high">
  <input type="hidden" value="2" name="medium">
  <input type="hidden" value="1" name="low">
  <input type="submit" name="submithost" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
echo "<td><input onchange='f1.submit()'; type='checkbox' class='i-checks' name='agency' value='" . $value1 . ":" . $agency_row["report_name"] . ":" . $agency_row["scan_start"] . ":" . $agency_row["scan_end"] . "'></td>"
```

to

```
$checked=(isset($_REQUEST['agency']) && $_REQUEST['agency'] == $value1) ? ' checked' : '';
echo "<td><input onchange='f1.submit()'; type='checkbox' class='i-checks' name='agency' value='" . $value1 . ":" . $agency_row["report_name"] . ":" . $agency_row["scan_start"] . ":" . $agency_row["scan_end"] . $checked ."'></td>"
```

Comment: Thanks @cmerriman for taking of your time! I did as you suggested, however, when I selected the input, it doesn't keep the checked but when I changed the code to `$checked=(isset($_REQUEST['agency']) && $_REQUEST['agency'] == $value1) ? '' : 'checked';` all the cells are checked even on refresh. Again, thanks and kind regards @cmerriman!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure... did the solution work for you as needed?

Comment: No, it didn't work. When I click on the input and the page reloads, the checks disappear.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you add the `$checked` at the end of the input tag?

Comment: Yes, I added the `$checked` at the end of input tag, just like you said. But I didn't work. I did some other tests: I moved the `$checked` to the beginning `<input onchange='f1.submit()'; $checked ....` and changed the variable `$checked` to `$checked=(isset($_REQUEST['agency']) && $_REQUEST['agency'] == $value1) ? '' : 'checked';` and all the cells were checked automatically. If I don't move the `$checked` to the beginning of the input all the cells aren't checked. Again: Thanks a lot!

Comment: I found an error in my code. I had declared a variable `$checked` in my code in a part that I didn't post. But now after I deleted the old variable and I click on the check, everything is checked on the table.

Comment: Cool.  Glad it worked. And welcome to StackOverflow.  If the answer did get you to your solution, please mark it as accepted.